# Datatables.net ColReorder (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I am using datatables.net (working super smooth) and added the plugin "ColReorder" (since I want to reorder columns, obviously).

```
ERROR in src/app/components/example-table/example-table.component.ts:51:24 - error TS2339: Property 'ColReorder' does not exist on type 'StaticFunctions'.

51     new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder( table, {
```

So for some reason he does  not know "ColRecorder" - but when I open my webpage in browser and remove the iframe which is showing the ERROR everything is working perfectly fine. I can also reorder my columns and everything is as expected.

Sadly my visual studio is showing me the same error but no solution for it.

[image]

The packages are installed (and working) - maybe I forgot to include them somewehere?
Any ideas? Thank you so much!